# Asp validation decimal not binded correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a problem with the asp-validation.
I have a decimal field which I want to be between 0.00 and 1.00.

Here is my **model** :

```
public class Intent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Language Language_ { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
    [Range(0.00, 1.00)]
    public decimal Tolerance { get; set; }
    public LuisApp LuisAppFr_ { get; set; }
    public LuisApp LuisAppEn_ { get; set; }
    public LuisApp LuisAppNl_ { get; set; }
    public string UrlImage { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the signature of my **post method**:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Active,Tolerance,UrlImage,Language_,Language_.TextEn,Language_.TextFr,Language_.TextNl")] Intent intent)
```

Here is a part of my **Create View**:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input asp-for="Active" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Active)
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Tolerance" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Tolerance" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Tolerance" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

[Here is an image showing the value of my Tolerance field when it gets to the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPBcW.png)

[And here is an image of my network request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV30J.png)

[Error Message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqSFx.png)

The binding seems to be good on the frontend but isn't in the backend.
Has anyone an idea of what my error could be ?

Thanks forward for your answer.
Sorry if it's a repost.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine and will bind correctly, so I assume its something you have not shown us causing the issue. Are the other properties of you model binding correctly. And what is the signature of you post method?

Comment: Just added the signature of my post and the error message i get

Comment: What is the culture on the server? Is it one that expects a `.` (dot) as the decimal separator?

Comment: Seems like it was a problem of culture :). Just solved it thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding this in my startup.cs :

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US")
        });
```